# How to make a KeyDown work twice

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on a little story type thing in visual basic. Nothing too complicated but i have run into a problem. I am trying to make a pause feature. I have it all working to when i press escape, the form goes into a menu type thing. The only problem is that it only works once. The first press works, but if i hit continue, it continues from where i left off. But if i press it again, nothing happens. Here is the code i am using:

```
Private Sub Story_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
        Text.Hide()
        Background.Hide
        ContinueButton.Show
        OptionsButton.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there any way for me to make this work more than just once? I am using a KeyDown event in a private sub.

Hope this made sense, but thanks for any help guys!

Comment: Please include some code of your events and handlers

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint, do you hit it the second time?

Comment: I think you're losing focus on the form on pressing escape.. Try repositioning the focus (by clicking on the form) and re-press escape. If it works, then, then try forcing the focus programmatically on a control at the end of your event

Answer (score 0):

You're using Form.KeyPreview = true to capture the form keystrokes. I think `Text.Hide()` or one of  `Show` operations could be the problem such as getting the TabStop's out of order or leaving a gap in the tab sequence.

Try resetting the controls or using SendKeys to reset the tab sequence index (to the approriate a control to have focus), For example, Tab forward and Alt Tab back:

```
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
```

or

```
SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}");
```

Ref:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I took a look at what you are saying but i dont fully understand what you are tying to say. I want it so when i press the escape key, It hides everything on the page and displays a few things for a pause type menu. But when i press a continue button i made, it hides everything to do with the pause menu and shows everything again once more. This works, but only once. I need it to show the menu every time i press the escape key. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using a class level boolean as toggle should work:

```
Dim Hide As Boolean = False
Private Sub Story_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
        Hide = Not Hide          
        If Hide Then
            Text.Hide()
            Background.Hide
            ContinueButton.Show
            OptionsButton.Show
        Else
            Text.Show()
            Background.Show
            ContinueButton.Hide
            OptionsButton.Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using your code and it works great for when i press the escape key twice, the only problem now is that when i click the continue button that i made, i can no longer press escape to open the menu again? Any idea's

Comment: Edit your original post and show the continue button click code and any routines that it calls.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else helps, you can always have a private class-level variable like `_processingKeyDown`, set to `True` at handler start, and then to `False` when done. The first line in the handler would be:

```
If _processingKeyDown Then Return
```